# Error while input an index (Python 3.6) only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I was trying to run https://github.com/AppliedDataSciencePartners/DeepReinforcementLearning on jupyter notebook and everything was fine until I execute this block.

```
from game import Game
from funcs import playMatchesBetweenVersions

import loggers as lg

env = Game()

playMatchesBetweenVersions(env, 2, -1, 26, 1, lg.logger_tourney,0, 1)
```

Where the important part is that -1 is for a human player if I run this, this happens. [Ask for imput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JcbB.png)

when entering a valid input this is what happens. [IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLVaY.png)

Comment: On line 26, `action=int(input("Enter your chosen answer: "))`

Comment: Please upvote and mark the answer as Accepted if this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file

> D:\Codigo fuente\agent.py

on line 26

```
action = input('Enter your chosen action: ')
```

`action` variable is of type string. You need to convert `action` variable to int for indexing.

It should be

```
action = int(input('Enter your chosen action: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line 26 to:

`action=int(input("Enter your chosen answer: "))`

as I mentioned in the comments.